# Flush an asynchronous logger on SIGSEGV C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have an asynchronous logger that writes logs to a file with a worker thread. It keeps a queue of messages and writes them to disk in order.

If my program triggers a segmentation fault, then I am not guaranteed to print all messages.

I am thinking of using `std::signal` to catch a `SIGSEGV`, flush the asynchronous logger, and then exiting the program.

Is this reasonable? Or is behavior totally undefined after a segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: IMHO, logging can be done in a separate process, not a thread, so if your main-process dies then the logging-process stays alive and is capable of detecting the main-process death to act accordingly.

Comment: *If my program triggers a segmentation fault* -- I think your main concern should be why your program produces a segmentation fault.  If you try to do other things in your app after the seg fault occurs, you risk losing crash related information.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior after receiving SIGSEGV is definitely not undefined in general, some JVMs generate NullPointerExceptions from actual null pointers being dereferenced.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html for what is officially allowed in a signal handler.

In the frequent case of a NULL or uninitialized pointer access, chances are good that the actual problem is localized in the thread triggering the SEGV, and flushing the logger works fine. Of course, as @paulmckenzie already explained, it is a trade-off between the additional information gained from flushing the logger and the risk of having no information at all.